# Implementation of greateast N per group with Laravel's query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, greatest-n-per-group, fluent, query-builder

The problem is to implement the nested query on the second INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.b = t1.b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a, max(c) AS d FROM t3 GROUP BY a
) AS t3 ON ( t3.a = t1.a AND t3.d = t1.c )
```

I've try a lot of test with closure on join() function, but it seems to be only for nested where.

I've find [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) that my SQL command can be write with an other form easier to write with query builder, but less trivial. So I wonder if the above SQL query can still be write with Laravel4's Query Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a fun one.

```
$products = DB::table('t1')
    ->select('a', 'b', 'c')
    ->join('t2', 't2.b', '=', 't1.b')
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT a, max(c) AS d FROM "articles" GROUP BY a) AS t3'), function($join)
    {
        $join->on('t3.a', '=', 't1.a');
        $join->on('t3.d', '=', 't1.c');
    })
    ->toSql();

echo $products;
```

It's outputting correctly for me but with the inclusion of some parenthesis around what you are joining t3 on.  I don't see it making any difference for you though.  You may have to change `"articles"` to just `articles` because I don't think that will work correctly.

Comment: Oh I forgot to replace "articles" by "t3" in my example when I've try to generalize my query. As far as I understand it's not possible to avoid DB::raw for nested queries?

Comment: Does the two $join->on() into the callbackfunction work like an `and`?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what they are doing.  It won't be possible without a raw statement because if you try doing `->join('(select a, max(c) as d FROM articles GROUP BY a) as t3', 't3.a', '=', 't1.a')`, it will put ticks before and after like it's one long table name.

Comment: Notice I'm using `toSql()` rather than `get()`.  This will convert it to SQL first so you can echo it to make sure it's doing what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I didn't know them !